# Python asynchronous call separate functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-requests, concurrent.futures

I have 4 functions as follows, 3 of them call an external apis to fetch random data:

```
def get_external_data(zip_code, info_code):
    data_url = MY_ENDPOINT_1.format(zip_code)
    data_response = requests.request(
        'GET',
        url=data_url,
        headers={
            'content-Type': 'application/json',
            'info-code': info_code
        }
    )
    return data_response

def get_info(info_code):
    info_url = INFO_URL.format(info_code)
    info_response = requests.request(
        'GET',
        url=info_url,
        headers={
            'content-Type': 'application/json',
            'info-code': info_code
        }
    )
    return info_response

def get_zip(zip_code):
    zip_url = zip_URL.format(zip_code)
    zip_response = requests.request(
        'GET',
        url=zip_url,
        headers={
            'content-Type': 'application/json',
            'zip-code': zip_code
        }
    )
    return zip_response

def get_all_data(info_cd, zip_code):
    data_response = get_external_data(zip_code, info_cd)
    info_response = get_info(info_cd)
    zip_response = get_zip(zip_code)
    return data_response, info_response, zip_response
```

I am trying to achieve 3 asynchronous calls by calling the 3 data functions using `concurrent.futures` in the `get_all_data()` function. From the docs i understand that we can thread one function with a list of inputs as follows:

```
resp_list = list()
# Asynchronous
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
    thread_responses = executor.map(self.get_info, info_list)
    for x in thread_responses:
        resp_list.append(x)
```

But how will i achieve 3 threads in this particular situation with 3 different functions with different inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make each call in its own thread using `executor.submit`, like this:

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
    data_future = executor.submit(get_external_data, zip_code, info_cd)
    info_future = executor.submit(get_info, info_cd)
    zip_future = executor.submit(get_zip, zip_code)
    # and then collect results
    results = [
        f.result()
        for f in (data_future, info_future, zip_future)
    ]
```

See related docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.submit